# Scala type mismatch when composing traits

Tags: scala, generics, types

I am trying to compute some types that I later need to refer to.

I am trying to achieve this by storing the types in type members.

Here's an example:

```
trait TypeClass[A] {
    def op(x: A): A
}

object TypeClass {

    implicit object FloatIsTypeClass extends TypeClass[Float] {
        override def op(x: Float) = x
    }

    implicit object DoubleIsTypeClass extends TypeClass[Double] {
        override def op(x: Double) = x
    }
}


object TraitBounds {

    trait Types1 {
        type Member1
        val cls1: TypeClass[Member1]
    }

    class Types1Impl[A](implicit ev: TypeClass[A]) extends Types1 {
        type Member1 = A
        override val cls1 = ev
    }

    trait Types2 {
        type Member2
        val cls2: TypeClass[Member2]
    }

    class Types2Impl[A](implicit ev: TypeClass[A]) extends Types2 {
        type Member2 = A
        override val cls2 = ev
    }

    trait AllTypes extends Types1 with Types2

    def mk(x: Int): AllTypes = {
        import TypeClass._

        val (instance1, instance2) =
            if (x == 1) {
                (new Types1Impl[Float](), new Types2Impl[Double]())
            } else {
                (new Types1Impl[Double](), new Types2Impl[Float]())
            }

        new AllTypes {
            override type Member1 = instance1.Member1
            override val cls1 = instance1.cls1
            override type Member2 = instance2.Member2
            override val cls2 = instance2.cls2
        }
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val in = mk(1)
        println(in)
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(54, 43) type mismatch;
 found   : TypeClass[_1]
 required: TypeClass[this.Member1]
    (which expands to)  TypeClass[_1]
            override val cls1 = instance1.cls1
```

It seems to me that I am expressing something that should be acceptable but for some reason the compiler does not understand what I'm trying to do (or maybe I'm wrong).

Why am I getting the type error? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there are some errors regarding the type system, especially in this line `val (instance1, instance2) =`, since in one branch of the **if** `instance1` is of type `Types1Impl[Float]` and in the other is of type `Types1Impl[Double]`, it may be inferred as of type `Types1Impl[AnyVal]` and maybe that's what causes the problem, but I don't know too much about the compiler to know the exact reason.

However, I gave a little refactor to your code and its working for me.

```
trait TypeClass[A] {
  def op(x: A): A
}

object TypeClass {
  implicit val FloatIsTypeClass: TypeClass[Float] = new TypeClass[Float] {
    override def op(x: Float): Float = x
  }

  implicit val DoubleIsTypeClass: TypeClass[Double] = new TypeClass[Double] {
    override def op(x: Double): Double = x
  }
}

object TraitBounds {
  trait Types1 {
    type Member1
    val cls1: TypeClass[Member1]
  }

  object Types1 {
    private class Types1Impl[A](implicit ev: TypeClass[A]) extends Types1 {
      override type Member1 = A
      override val cls1 = ev
    }

    def apply[A: TypeClass]: Types1 = new Types1Impl[A]
  }

  trait Types2 {
    type Member2
    val cls2: TypeClass[Member2]
  }

  object Types2 {
    private class Types2Impl[A](implicit ev: TypeClass[A]) extends Types2 {
      override type Member2 = A
      override val cls2 = ev
    }

    def apply[A: TypeClass]: Types2 = new Types2Impl[A]
  }

  trait AllTypes extends Types1 with Types2
  object AllTypes {
    def fromTypes(t1: Types1, t2: Types2): AllTypes = new AllTypes {
      override type Member1 = t1.Member1
      override val cls1 = t1.cls1
      override type Member2 = t2.Member2
      override val cls2 = t2.cls2
    }
  }

  def mk(x: Int): AllTypes =
    if (x == 1) {
      AllTypes.fromTypes(Types1[Float], Types2[Double])
    } else {
      AllTypes.fromTypes(Types1[Double], Types2[Float])
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val in: AllTypes = mk(1)
    println(in)
  }
}
```

A couple of notes, always prefer *implicit* `vals` and `defs` with specific **type signatures** over *implicit* `objects`, they tend up to mess the type system since an object is of type `ThatObjectName.type`.
Also, hide your implementations behind factory constructors to shadow their **types** to the parent `trait`.